# What method can I use to get a different date value for a stored field in my database?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am working on a project that is asking me to return different date values based on the scenario and I am not quite sure how to write this out. I think that I'm just not understanding how to apply the logic:

- `PAYFREQ` is `A` then `TRANS_DATE` is 1st of the Year of `COMPEFFDT`
- `PAYFREQ` is `M` then `TRANS_DATE` is 1st of the Month of `COMPEFFDT`
- `PAYFREQ` is `B` then 1st day of the biweekly period ending with `COMPEFFDT`
- `PAYFREQ`  <> `A` and the only non-zero `FIC` amount for a calendar year has `COMPEFFDT` of December 31, then `TRANS DATE` is 1st of the Year of `COMPEFFDT`

Can anyone give me at least a base starting point in how to formulate this statement?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and any attempt you have made to write a query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in a query, try the SWITCH statement. I'm not sure what you mean by the "1st of year of COMPEFFDT" though.

SELECT SWITCH ( 
               PAYFREQ = "A", "1st of year of COMPEFFDT", 
               PAYFREQ = "M", "1st of the Month of COMPEFFDT",
               ...
              ) AS Result

Also, you should look at the guide for submitted a new question.